# PHP ping IP:Port

Tags: php, ping

I want to Ping a server based on IP and Port. Why port?
Because the system that I am building will have Login Server and Game server on different PORTS
Right Now I am using fsockopen

```
        $start = microtime(true);
        $fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
        if (!$fp) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $ping = microtime(true) - $start;
            $ping = round($ping * 1000);
            $res['ip'] = $host;
            $res['port'] = $port;
            $res['ping'] = $ping;
            $res['msg'] = 'success';
            return $res;
        }
```

I cant and I don't wan't to use exec() 1. The IP and Port will be inputed by user and exec() cant ping on port.

with fsockopen I can take only latency (that is not so correct).

If anybody know how cant I get Latensy, Packets send|recived, Jitter and etc.

Maybe some sort of 3rd party API for PHP Ping.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Duplicate? there no answer on hot to ping IP+PORT without  fsockopen

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Anyway, can you elaborate on your situation? Ping works on ICMP protocol, does the Login Server/Game Server on the stated different ports use ICMP as well ? I think that they should if you want to actually use "ping".

Comment: Yes Login Server/Game Server use ICMP

Comment: If your services don't support a ping dialog you should stay at ICMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [socket_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) since ping uses ICMP and fsockopen is only for TCP and UDP. ICMP echo packets do not specify any port. In the socket_create manual, in the user comments there are several ping() example implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You can check ICMP packet format in [RFC 792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792)

While ICMP is layer3 protocol, but port number is defined in layer4. So you never find port number in ICMP packet

That means, you can get latency between two host(IP) , but you can't get latency between IP:ports .